# Invoke any method with unknown amount of variables from another method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import time

def f(method,timeout,condition=False,*args,**kwargs):
    t_end=time.time() +timeout
    while time.time()<t_end:
        ret=method(*args,**kwargs)
        if condition:
            return ret
    return ret

def f2(a,b):
    print(a,b)
def f3(a):
    print(a)
```

The question is: how to invoke method f so it can work with arguments f2 and f3 eg. `f(f2,2,*(1,2))`  And I don't want to use @decorator.

Comment: You forgot to account for the `condition` parameter. Use `f(f2, 2, False, *(1,2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

condition=False is a keyword argument. So move it next to *args.
Other than that, just pass arguments depending on the function you pass.

```
import time

def f(method, timeout, *args, condition=False, **kwargs):
    t_end = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < t_end:
        ret = method(*args,**kwargs)
        if condition:
            return ret
    return ret

def f2(a, b):
    print(a, b)
def f3(a):
    print(a)

f(f2, 2, *(1,2))
f(f3, 2, 1)
```